# Postgresql: Append % to the start and end of an array elements

Tags: postgresql

I have an array elements in my query to which I need to add % at start and end.

```
Table friends
id   type    keywords
1    Close    beverage,party,cool
2    Close    party
3    Close    beverage
4     Far     beverage
```

Currently my Query:

```
select id from friends f where f.type = 'Close' and ('BEVERAGE ALLOWED' ilike any((string_to_array(f.keywords,',')))
```

In the above query `(string_to_array(f.keywords,','))` convert keywords to an array such as: `{beverage,party,cool}`.
But I need to add % sign to the start and end of each element so that the array elements are as:  `{%beverage%,%party%,%cool%}`

Comment: I deleted my answer - here @Abelisto `concat('{%',replace('beverage,party,cool',',','%,%'),'%}')` from comments

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to generate your array:

```
string_to_array('%' || replace(f.keywords, ',', '%,%') || '%', ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `~*` operator instead of `ilike`:

```
select id
from friends f
where
  f.type = 'Close' and 
  ('BEVERAGE ALLOWED' ~* any((string_to_array(f.keywords,',')))
```

[Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

or `SIMILAR TO`:

```
select id
from friends f
where
  f.type = 'Close' and 
  (upper('BEVERAGE ALLOWED') SIMILAR TO '%(' || upper(replace(f.keywords,',','|')) || ')%')
```

[Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP)

Note that the `SIMILAR TO` is case-sensitive so we have to use `upper()` function.

However it does not handle properly cases like

```
select
  'foobar' ~* any(array['FOO','BAR']),
  'foobar' ilike any(array['%FOO%','%BAR%']);
```

(both condidions returns `true`)

There are a lot of ways how to solve it. One of the possible: [Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html):

```
select
  to_tsvector('FOOBAR') @@ to_tsquery('foo|bar'),
  to_tsvector('FOO BAR') @@ to_tsquery('foo|bar');
```

Or, for your query:

```
select id
from friends f
where
  f.type = 'Close' and 
  (to_tsvector('BEVERAGE ALLOWED') @@ to_tsquery(replace(f.keywords,',','|'));
```